# How do I reset $wp_query in a function?

Tags: php, wp-query

I'm using a function in my functions.php that finds a specific post in a custom post type depending on a slug. I was wondering if I need to reset $wp_query because I use `$wp_query = $posts` and `$wp_query->set_404()` ?

My problem is, that I'm not 100% sure where to put wp_reset_postdata() (and if I need to put it here). If I put it before the last "}" wouldn't the "exit" statement in the error handling prevent the function to get there?

```
add_action('parse_request', 'parse_requests', 0);
function parse_requests() {
    global $wp, $wp_query;
    if(isset($wp->query_vars['angebot'])) {
        // find the angebot post
        $posts = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'angebote',
            'name' => $wp->query_vars['angebot'],
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        ));
        if(!empty($posts) ) {
            // set the global query or set your own variable
            $wp_query = $posts;
            
        } else {
            // handle error
            $wp_query->set_404();
            status_header(404);
            locate_template('404.php', true);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to reset here. `wp_reset_postdata()` is only required if you're using `$posts->the_post()` or otherwise modifying the global `$post` variable.